# Is it possible to have certain apps only show up only in their respective virtual desktops?

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar

I want a virtual desktop with VS Code, Firefox, and Spotify but I don't want the those applications to show on my other VD's task bar. Sorry if this isn't the right forum for this.

Comment: I think you are looking for Software Recommendations site.  I use [VirtualWin](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/).  You can tell which  programs are to be fixed and which ones can move.  Combined with the windows setting of showing icons for tasks on that screen, this works like a charm for me.

Comment: What virtual desktops? The built in OS ones or 3rd party apps? What research have you done and what have you tried?